# Notice: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$mydb in [Path] in wamp server

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp, wampserver

I want to run `mongo` from `php` I am using `MongoDB 64 bit`, `WampServer 64 bit`, `Apache Version:
2.4.18` and  `PHP Version: 5.6.19`. I also added `mongodb.dll` extension in `php.ini` of `PHP` as well as in `php.ini` of `apache`. I have also installed `Composer` and run the command

```
composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"
```

On running the code below I am getting this error:

[image]

Connection to mongo is successful and db is also selected then why this error?

```
   require 'vendor/autoload.php';
   // connect to mongo
   $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
   echo "Connection to database successfully";

   // select a db
   $db = $m->mydb;
   echo "Database mydb selected";

?>
```

I also tried `$db = $m->test;` but getting the same error. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [MongoDB\Driver\Manager](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) doesn't have property `mydb`.

Comment: @KostyaZhevlakov `myDB`is the name of database. If it does not exist it should be made a new database under the name of `myDB`. Is'nt it?

Comment: @KostyaZhevlakov Then How can I connect to database ?

Comment: I persistenly recommend you to use  this [library](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/) - it will save your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved by adding

```
$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

instead of

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
```

Actually, I was calling the wrong class. :)

Comment: But `aggregate` and `$first` is not working if i use new `MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new MongoClient()
```

If you still get the error then it Looks like it can't load the Mongo Module.

First You have to download the stable dll zip file. [PHP-MONGO](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo)

Download the Threaded-version of the module. Copy the dll file and paste it in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.19\ext (if wamp). then go to your php.ini file and paste the following script: `extension=php_mongo.dll` in the extensions row.

**Note:** There shouldn't be a '**;**' before the extension . 
Then restart WAMP. In the wamp-php-extension menu you could find the *php_mongo*. **tick** mark it. Restart Wamp.

Start mongo and the try executing the following script.

```
<?php
    if($connection = new mongoClient()){
        echo "Connected Successfully";
     } 
?>`
```

**Note:** First start the Mongo server.

For more info: [PHP/Mongo Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php)

If you have problem in start Mongo then Write the command as follows in your Mongo/bin **directory**:

```
mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath [your-path]
```

your-path= The path you want to save the Databse files. (ex: F:\data\db )

The Mongo sever would be running now. **Don't close the cmd**.

Comment: [php_mongo](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongo/1.6.14/php_mongo-1.6.14-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip) <=  (link)    You can find the dll in the zip file. Unzip this file and paste it in your wamp-php extensions folder and follow the steps in my above answer.

Comment: Your method is not working. I am getting `Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\wamp64\www\mongo2.php on line 2`

Comment: @Amar The dll problem still exists. Make sure you had placed the dll in right place.  Php5.6 extension folder,added the extension script and tick marked the php_mongo in wamp-php menu. Restart wamp.