# How to use mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi I am trying to connect to mongoDB with Php7 using following code

```
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

but getting following error:

> [:error] [pid 6069] [client 127.0.0.1:35118] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$clients

Where `$clients` is the mongodb database I am trying to connect to. MongoDB extension is installed and included in Php.ini like this:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

When connecting to clients database as follows

```
$db = $connection->clients;
```

I get this error:

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

phpinfo() is also showing driver installed as shown in the following screenshot [image: phpinfo]

I am running apache2 server on localhost. Any idea what could be the problem??

EDIT: If I do `var_dump($connection)` I get following:

> object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) { ["uri"]=> string(25) "mongodb://localhost:27017" ["cluster"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Did you try `$connection = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

Comment: in an empty php file write : `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`  and search Mongo for checking mongoDB extension is enabled or no

Comment: @callback I tried now then I got this error

Comment: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\\Client' not found

Comment: @Eskandari It says "MongoDB extension version 1.2.8" as shown in the screenshot included in question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530590/notice-undefined-property-mongodb-driver-managermydb-in-path-in-wamp-serv

Comment: That link did not solve the problem either

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code including the part where you are  connecting to `$clients` database ?

Comment: @Veeram sure I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to query using Manager api is below. It doesn't have access to the db object.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php

Here is an example

```
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$id           = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId(SomeId);
$filter      = ['_id' => $id];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);

$cursor = $connection->executeQuery('DatabaseNameHere.CollectionNameHere', $query);
```

Alternate way of query is to use Client api through composer loader.

Installation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/install-php-library/

Tutorials

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/