# How can i configure xampp to install php mongo driver for latest version of php version 7.1 and connect to mongodb from php script

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

I am using window 10 ,xampp php version 7.1.1 ,architecture x86,vc14 and i have configure my xampp for connect to mongo database and mogodb extension is shown on my php_info page but still i am unable to connect to mongodb with php script.

What i have done till now on my window 10 is listing as below.

- install mongodb v3.4.3 and it work fine, i have run mogod on console and perform mongodb operation on window shell .
- install xampp v3.2.2 stack,php v7.1.1,architecture x86,vc14,thread safe enable
- download php_mongodb-1.2.8-7.1-ts-vc14-x64 driver and paste it to xampp/php/ext
- add extension to php.ini file in  xampp as extension=php_mongodb.dll

and it show mongodb extension to php_info page as
[image]

- i try this script to connect to mongo db

  ```
  echo 'connection to mongodb database successfully';

  //select database
  $db=$m->martvalley;

  echo 'databse:martvalley is selected';

  $coll=$db->seller;

  echo 'collection seller is sellected from database:martvalley';

  $doc=array(
          'id'=>'4',
          'seller_name'=>'hello seller'
      );

  $coll->insert($doc);

  echo 'document inserted in collection:seller of database:martvaley';
  ```

but show me this error on browser

**Notice: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$martvalley in D:\php\htdocs\MongoDB-Script\select-db.php on line 8**

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\php\htdocs\MongoDB-Script\select-db.php on line 12**

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in D:\php\htdocs\MongoDB-Script\select-db.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\php\htdocs\MongoDB-Script\select-db.php on line 21**

it may be possibly dublicate of other question,but i could not got any proper solution to resolve this issue,any detail desciption are also appreciable because i am little bit confuse by others answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use mongodb extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307942/how-to-use-mongodb-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Use the newer one for PHP Version 7:

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb