# MongoDB with php fails to create collection

Tags: php, mongodb, mlab

It shows the following error and no new collections are created in the mlab database.

> Connected
>   ( ! ) Notice: Undefined property:
>   MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$helfis in C:\wamp\www\mongo.php on line 11
>   Database mydb selected
>   ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function createCollection() on a non-object in > C:\wamp\www\mongo.php on line 13

Here's my PHP Code:

```
<?php

    $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongo_url");

    echo "Connected";

    $db = $m->helfis;
    echo "Database mydb selected";
    $collection = $db->createCollection("myhell");
    echo "Collection created succsessfully";

    $collection = $db->dashboard;
    echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

?>
```

Comment: use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530590/notice-undefined-property-mongodb-driver-managermydb-in-path-in-wamp-serv for getting your problem solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$mydb in \[Path\] in wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530590/notice-undefined-property-mongodb-driver-managermydb-in-path-in-wamp-serv)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["create" => 'testcollection']);

    $cursor = $this->mgoManagerObj->executeCommand("testdb", $command);
    $response = $cursor->toArray()[0];
    var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.